# ansible process yaml blocks (arrays) line values

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have a shell command, which stdout lines are a YAML array, which looks like this:

```
success: 1
message:
system:
  version: X.Y
  tier: STABLE
data:
  destinations:
    0:
      _id: 5f7de84eab8cee6deb0795a2
      type: SSH
      name: backup1
      engine_name:
      rating:
        rating: 6.324084213116
        issues:
      jobs_count: 0
      owner: root
      ...
    1:
      _id: 5f7de850e4ef1d17520fee82
      type: SSH
      name: backup2
      engine_name:
      rating:
        rating: 6.3627132233357
        issues:
      jobs_count: 0
      owner: root
      ...
  total: 2
```

(Sanitized a lot of unwanted lines, but the structure is the same) I would like to process the arrays in `data: destinations: array number:` `_id:` and `name:` values and store it in values (using set fact would be the best), but I have no idea how to start at all. The playbook should look like this:

```
- name: list backup destinations
  command: 'mycommand'
  register: result

- name: process the result but I don't know how to do that
  set_fact:
    destinationX_name: ...
    destinationX_id: ...
```

And the result should look like this from the above output:

```
destination0_name: backup1
destination0_id: 5f7de84eab8cee6deb0795a2
destination1_name: backup2
destination1_id: 5f7de850e4ef1d17520fee82
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, I think I figured it out. The proper and easy way would be:

```
- name: list backup destinations
  command: 'mycommand'
  register: result

- name: process the result
  set_fact:
    destination0_name: "{{ (result.stdout | from_yaml).data.destinations.0.name }}"
    destination1_name: "{{ (result.stdout | from_yaml).data.destinations.1.name }}"
    destination0_id: "{{ (result.stdout | from_yaml).data.destinations.0._id }}"
    destination1_id: "{{ (result.stdout | from_yaml).data.destinations.1._id }}"

...
```

Then I can process the variables from the fact.

Answer (score 0):

The tasks below

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_vars: "{{ my_vars|default({})|
                     combine({my_key: my_val}) }}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ data.destinations.keys()|list }}"
        - [_id, name]
      vars:
        my_key: "{{ 'destination' ~ item.0 ~ '_' ~ item.1 }}"
        my_val: "{{ data.destinations[item.0][item.1] }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_vars
```

give

```yaml
  my_vars:
    destination0__id: 5f7de84eab8cee6deb0795a2
    destination0_name: backup1
    destination1__id: 5f7de850e4ef1d17520fee82
    destination1_name: backup2
```

Comment: After trying some scenario, it also does not work for me. The original `command: mycommand` and `register: my_vars` task runs, but after that, I applied your answer and the error message is: `FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'my_key' is undefined` Should I define it in the command task or what am I doing worng?